# Make a float "between" parts

Tags: floats, positioning

Well say I have a float (figure/table) - how can I make it so this float is **always** before a certain piece of text (and always after another).

If the float would switch to the page the next it should be before should also drop to the next page. So basically I have:

```
\begin{document}
....lots of text BEFORE IMAGE...

...part where image can move around inside....
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
...lots of text after image....
\end{docuement}
```

The "part where image can move around inside" the image should (ideally) behave just as if it is was marked with `[h]`. But it most definitelly should not move after/before the boundaries. Even if  that means adding white pages/not using half the page.

Comment: `placeins` package and `\FloatBarrier` or its `[section]` option to put a barrier automatically on each section

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well problem with floatbarrier seems to be that it doesn't prevent images to go "higher" (so before the text you wish it to go). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: for that you also want `flafter` package (part of the base latex distrib)

Comment: Compiling those in an answer would allow me to mark this question solved :P. - I take it you can use both packages at the same time (flafter as well as placeins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `placeins` package provides a `\FloatBarrier` command that automatically inserts `\clearpage` at points if there are pending floats. It's `section` option adds this automatically to every section.

To prevent floats moving to the top of the page with their callout you can use the standard `flafter` package which has no options or commands but just re-arranges the float placemnt algorithm so that the "top" position is only considered on later pages which means that floats only appear after their position in the source file.